# How can I have a common column header for my table having expandable sections inside which includes the table rows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-tables, antd

I am using Ant Design to create a table. I understand it is a row by column approach to create a table. But in my requirement, I want to create a table having expandable sections. These sections would be containing the table rows. While I can use the expandedRowRender() provided by Ant-D, I want the column headers of the table rows to be outside the section and common to all the rows. My section need not have a column header in my requirement. If any possible way can be suggested, it would be helpful to me. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you sketch out an example? For example, what exactly does the table look like before being expanded if the rows are inside of the expansion? I'm having trouble visualizing what you are trying to accomplish.

I might be mistaken but it sounds like using `expandedRowRender` to render a sub-table and setting `showHeader` false in the sub-table to hide the column headers might accomplish your spec.